How can I calculate the sizes of the bounding boxes for a particular YOLOv5 class?
I have n classes that the Ultralytics YOLOv5 model is currently detecting. How can I get the average of the sizes of the bounding boxes for one particular class?
I tried back calculating the bounding box co-ordinates and then running a loop through all the label text files.
